# Как лучше сделать переключение тем?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть игра в которой я хочу реализовать возможность смены темы игры, но для этого нужно для каждого элемента присваивать отделенный спрайт, но как лучше это сделать, как лучше сделать возможность получить доступ ко всем спрайтам? Как я понимаю, отдельный массив всех спрайтов для каждого элемента, объявленный в скрипте, будет не самым лучшим решением...

Comment: Во-первых, для начала было бы неплохо как-то описать сущность "Тема" в своей игре для упрощения ее смены. Во-вторых, создайте папку "Resources" и пользуйтесь [`Resources.Load`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) для загрузки префабов или спрайтов для темы/тем Вашей игры.

Comment: 1 атлас == 1 тема, свапайте атласы и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский скажем так, есть игровое меню, и я хочу сделать два вида тем: Зеленая и Желтая. Когда я нажимаю на кнопку все кнопки меняют темы, например: Все кнопки сначала зеленой расцветки, а после нажатия желтой, вот что я подразумеваю под темой

Comment: @RiotBr3aker как вариант

Comment: @RiotBr3aker да , все работает как надо, напишите ответ чтоб я мог отметить его как решение, спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массивы спрайтов принято паковать в специальные атласы - [Sprite Atlas](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/U2D.SpriteAtlas.html). Процедура "извлечения" спрайтов из атласа - [`SpriteAtlas.GetSprites`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/U2D.SpriteAtlas.GetSprites.html), дальнейший доступ к конкретным спрайтам осуществляется через индексы в обычном массиве. Это значит, что и код для получения конкретных спрайтов будет идентичен.

Учитывая эту реализацию, можно паковать UI темы в отдельные атласы и сменять эти атласы в зависимости от выбранной темы:

```
// Сменяемый атлас
[SerializeField]
SpriteAtlas uiAtlas;

void SetUiTheme(){
    var uiSprites = new Sprite[uiAtlas.spriteCount];
    uiAtlas.GetSprites(uiSprites);

    // доступ к спрайтам по индексам
    // uiSprites[0], uiSprites[1], и т.д.
}
```